# How to use $ionicPosition.position

Tags: ionic-framework

With this test content:

```
<ion-content class="has-header" delegate-handle="menu">
   <div id="activeitem">Test</div>
   <button ng-click="vm.scrollToActiveElement()">Test Scroll</button>
</ion-content>
```

I want to get the position of the `activeitem` element:

```
vm.scrollToActiveElement = function () {

    var elem = document.getElementById('activeitem');
    if (!elem)
        return;
    var position = $ionicPosition.position(elem);     

};
```

But the call to `$ionicPosition.position` results in this error:

> Cannot read property 'getBoundingClientRect' of undefined

Comment: Have you found out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there.In fact this method is very poorly documented in ionic docs.

What I figured out after digging through source code is, since these methods are jQuery equivalent which always returns array of elements, the passed parameter to these functions should be an **array** with 0th index pointing to actual DOM as shown below

```js
vm.scrollToActiveElement = function() {

  var elem = document.getElementById('activeitem');
  if (!elem)
    return;
  var position = $ionicPosition.position([elem]); //not just elem    

};
/*it returns the offset of param[0] 
where param is the parameter passed to this function
*/

/*That is we need to wrap the dom element inside array as these methods are inspired 
from jQuery and jQuery wraps the matched element inside array 
  
If you are using AngularJS's jqLite, please verify if actual 
DOM is in array 0th position or not

*/
```